# Rep widget seems to overwrite SE app's cache

Tags: bug, android-app, caching, android-app-widgets

I can live with a little cache lag. But this one is a little weird: I thought the widget was using the same data as the SE app...

So the widget lags behind (I'm fine with that) and says I have 28,035 CR rep. If I open up my profile in the SE app I can see that it's actually 28,252. Now if I close it and click the widget, it brings up my user profile in the SE app, but showing 28,035 rep - reaching for the left panel to refresh my profile brings back the 28,252, but then the widget remains at 28,035.

I would expect the widget to somehow share this cached info with the SE app, and to update itself when the app refreshes it.

Would that be possible?

(sent from the most used app on my Android phone - I don't know if this also applies to the iOS version)

Comment: nah.. I know the feeling. The widget seems to lag behind up to **two days** sometimes (not to mention, that clicking it does *nothing*)

Comment: @Vogel612 yup. Still 28,035 ...after 2 days (and I bet tomorrow it will still be that)